# Redirect to HTML page executes before ASYNC functions save image and data of user to server. AWAIT not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

everyone! I have problem with async/await functions.

This is code from my backend. I try to save information of the person who just registered.

I really don't understand why `Redirect()` function executes before functions with `await`. All executes in async function. Main problem of this is empty "login","email" and user's profile picture sections on the profile page. Profile page gets login, email and profile from server with AJAX and when server redirects to this page nothing is loaded. But if I refresh profilePage, login, email and profile picture show up, what tells me that it is just haven't downloaded yet when redirection starts. It would be great if someone, who understand what is going on, will explain situation

```
app.post('/regPage.html', (req, res) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
        uploadDir: __dirname + '\\uploads',
        keepExtensions : true,
        maxFileSize : 10*1024*1024,
        multiples : true,
    });
    console.log(form);
    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
            if(err) console.error(err);
            let userData = fields;
            console.log(fields);
            console.log(files);
            async function createUserFolder() {
                    fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, `/users/${fields.login}`),{ recursive: true }, err => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('User folder created...');
                        return;
                    });
            }
            await createUserFolder();
            console.log(typeof fields);
            console.log('Right after consolelog files');
            async function writingDataToFolders() {
                    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, `/users/${fields.login}`, `${fields.login}.json`), JSON.stringify(userData),
                err => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("User file created...")
                }
            );
            //if(files.profilePic.originalFilename.split('.').pop() == undefined) {
                fs.rename(files.profilePic.filepath, path.join(__dirname, `/users/${fields.login}`, `${fields.login}_profilePic.${files.profilePic.originalFilename.split('.').pop()}`), function(err){
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        fs.unlink(files.profilePic.filepath, err => {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            console.log('Rename error on no profile pic');
                        });
                    }
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded");
                    return;
                });
            //}
            }

            // Data entry in MySQL, cookie generating
            let cookieId = uuid.v4();
            console.log(cookieId);
            async function writingDataToDatabase() {
                    let sql = 'SELECT cookieId FROM profiles WHERE cookieId= ?;';
                    let query = db.query(sql, cookieId, (err, results) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(results);
                if(results == "") {
                    console.log('No such CookieId in database!...');
                    const profileObjForMysql = {
                        login : fields.login,
                        email : fields.email,
                        password : fields.password,
                        cookieId : cookieId
                    }
                    //setCookie('ID', cookieId, 365);
                     sql = `INSERT INTO profiles SET ?;`;
                     query = db.query(sql, profileObjForMysql, (err, result) => {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        console.log(result);
                        console.log('Profile added to MySQL...');
                        return;
                    });
                }
            });
            }

            async function createNewUserEndpoints() {
                    let newUserEndpont =`\n \n router.get(\'/${fields.login}/${fields.login}_profilePic.${files.profilePic.originalFilename.split('.').pop()}\', (req, res) => {
                        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, \"/${fields.login}/${fields.login}_profilePic.${files.profilePic.originalFilename.split('.').pop()}\"));
                        console.log(\'Hello\');
                    });
                    router.get(\'/${fields.login}/${fields.login}.json\', (req, res) => {
                        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, \'/${fields.login}/${fields.login}.json\'));
                    }); \n`;
                    fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, `/users/users_router.js`,), newUserEndpont ,(err) => {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        return;
                    });
                    console.log('New endpoint for user added...');
                    
            }

            res.cookie('ID', cookieId, {httpOnly: false, maxAge : 999999999});

            
            await writingDataToFolders();
            console.log("Data was written to foldres...");
            await writingDataToDatabase();
            console.log("Data was written to Database...");
            await createNewUserEndpoints();
            console.log("New endpoint for user was created...");
            res.redirect(301, '/profilePage.html');
            
    });
});
```

I also tried contain all "await function_name" into function like this:

```
async function redirect() {
            await writingDataToFolders();
            console.log("Data was written to foldres...");
            await writingDataToDatabase();
            console.log("Data was written to Database...");
            await createNewUserEndpoints();
            console.log("New endpoint for user was created...");
            res.redirect(301, '/profilePage.html');
}

redirect();
```

but it didn't work too

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `async` functions are not really asynchronous, because you don't await the callback. One way to achieve this is to use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal), which converts the callback-flavored function into a function returning a promise, which you can `await`:

```js
async function createUserFolder() {
  await util.promisify(fs.mkdir)(
    path.join(__dirname, `/users/${fields.login}`),
    { recursive: true }
  ).then(() => {
    console.log('User folder created...');
  });
}
```

In other words: [`fs.mkdir`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsmkdirpath-options-callback) is a function that executes asynchronously and invokes a callback when done. `util.promisify(fs.mkdir)` is a function that returns a promise, which resolves when the asynchronous execution is done.

By contrast, [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsmkdirsyncpath-options) is a synchronous function which blocks the Node.js event loop. This should be avoided if you expect many parallel requests to your server.

Comment: Okay, so, how I understand this, fs.mkdir and fs.rename functions are asynchronously executes but they have no callback? 
Is there some way to carry this problem without `mkdirSync` or using `util.promisify`?

Comment: See my augmented answer. I recommend `util.promisify`.